# Google Analytics setup for Google Drive analysis?

Tags: google-analytics, google-drive-api, analytics, drive, google-apps-for-education

I am using Google Analytics within Google Apps for education and a shared Google Drive.

1. As a Google Apps admin, I can allow my users to use Google Analytics as an internal Google App. When I try to acces 
   http://www.google.com/analytics/a/mydomain as suggested in the Google Analytics settings page within Google Apps, I got a 404 error page. What does it mean? Is Google Analytics available for Google Apps and if yes, what can users expect from this service exactly?
2. I am interested in Google Anaytics for Google Drive to know more about our shared drive usage than I can get from the reporting section of the Google Admin console. Can Google Analytics be used for Google Drive and especially a shared Google Drive in the context of Google Apps for Education?
3. Any workaround involving tiers code?

Note I called Google Apps support and got a "app not supported, please refer to the community forums" answer...

Comment: mydomain is yourdomain not "mydomain" literally. type "google analytics" in google and it will take you there.

Comment: Thank you, it has been already granted for me that 'mydomain' was not to be taken literally. The fact is even spelling my own domain correctly, I get a 404 error page...

http://postimg.org/image/qcxu32wt9/

http://postimg.org/image/h6fjfsrkt/

I really wonder how to activate Google Analytics for the sake of getting deep stats on the use of a shared Google Drive itself.

Anyone knows where I could ask as Google Apps support told me they don't support Analytics?